# C# How to deleted multiple checked items from the CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, sql

i want to delete one or more selected items in checkedlistbox. But i dont know how i must to do that. Pls help

here my codes;

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            checkedListBox1.Items[checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
            SqlCommand del = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE personID='" + 
            personID[checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex] + "' ", con);

            con.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i]) //this line does not work
                {
                     del.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }       
            }
            con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a parameter for security reason.

Next you can set it in the loop with the desired id.

```
con.Open();
var command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE personID=? ", con);
var param = del.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int /* or any relevant type */);
foreach ( var item in checkedListBox1.SelectedItems )
{
  param.Value = ((TheTypeOfTheItems)item).NameOfTheID;
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
```

Perhaps you can construct only one query by adding some OR to the WHERE clause and execute it one time after the loop.

```
if ( checkedListBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 )
{
  con.Open();
  var command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE ", con);
  var id = ( (TheTypeOfTheItems)checkedListBox1.SelectedItems[index] ).NameOfTheID;
  command.CommandText += "personID =? ";
  command.Parameters.Add("@ID" + index, SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
  if ( checkedListBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 1 )
    for ( int index = 1; index < checkedListBox1.SelectedItems.Count; index++ )
    {
      command.CommandText += "OR ";
      var id = ( (TheTypeOfTheItems)checkedListBox1.SelectedItems[index] ).NameOfTheID;
      command.CommandText += "personID =? ";
      command.Parameters.Add("@ID" + index, SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    }
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
}
```

*Note: I can't test the code and I used params with odbc and not sql server.*

Comment: hi again. I tried your solutions but I couldn't do it, actually i dont understand.

especially this line
param.Value = ((TheTypeOfTheItems)item).NameOfTheID;

Comment: When you added items to the list, they had a certain type, I've called it `TheTypeOfTheItems`: that may be a data entity having a property ID, I've called it `NameOfTheID`. If you use int directly for example, use `.Value = (int)checkedListBox1.SelectedItems[index]`. Do you know this book [Beginning C# 2005 Databases](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Beginning+C%23+2005+Databases-p-9780470044063)? It is great to learn ADO.NET and WinForms Data Bindings step-by-step. There is [Beginning Visual C# 2008 Programming](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Beginning+Microsoft+Visual+C%23+2008-p-9780470191354) too.

Comment: I know these books are older, but the first is a must and no other offer that. And the second is excellent, even if after you may want read [Professional C# 7 and .NET Core 2.0](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Professional+C%23+7+and+NET+Core+2+0-p-9781119449263) or [others](http://www.ordisoftware.com/files/stack-overflow/CsharpBegin.htm).